# Getting the length of a Data.ByteString.Builder

Tags: haskell

I have a function `tabulate` that takes a list of objects, and a list of functions that turn fields of these objects into `Builders`. It returns a `Builder` representing a nicely formatted table. E.g.:

```
tabulate :: [a -> Builder] -> [a] -> Builder
tabulate = ...
data Assc = Assc { key :: String, value :: String }

> let funcs = [string7 . key, const $ char7 '=', string7 . value ]
> let objs = ["short" `Assc` "a", "longer" `Assc` "b", "waylongername" `Assc` "c"]
> hPutBuilder stdout $ tabulate funcs objs
short         = a
longer        = b
waylongername = c
```

To do this I need to determine the maximum length for each column. At the moment I am using `toLazyByteString` on each element (which is too slow).

Is it possible to get the length of a `Builder` without first turning it into a `ByteString`?

Alternatively, is there another way to (efficiently) implement `tabulate` (with or without using `Builder`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking into the source of [`Builder`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.2.0/docs/src/Data-ByteString-Builder-Internal.html#Builder), it's defined as

```
newtype Builder = Builder (forall r. BuildStep r -> BuildStep r)
```

So sequencing `Builder` is just composing functions, and there is no way how to get the length of the output without evaluating the stack of functions. But you could create your own helper module with a data type that would combine `Builder`s with length calculations:

```
newtype BuilderL = BuilderL { blLenght :: !Int, blBuilder :: Builder }

instance Monoid BuilderL where
    mempty = BuilderL 0 mempty
    mappend (BuilderL l1 t1) (BuilderL l2 t2) = BuilderL (l1 + l2) (t1 <> t2)
```

and then create helper functions for constructing `BuilderL`s, like

```
byteString :: ByteString -> BuilderL
byteString t = BuilderL (length t) (byteString t)
```

etc. Then use this module and `BuilderL` for your tables and you'll always have the length at hand.