# Space leak with wrapper around Data.ByteString.Builder

Tags: performance, haskell, memory

I have a wrapper type around `Data.ByteString.Builder` that allows me to track the length of the ByteString being built (cf. [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492205/getting-the-length-of-a-data-bytestring-builder)):

```
import Data.Monoid
import qualified Data.ByteString.Builder as B
import System.IO (stdout)

data LBuilder = LBuilder { toBuilder :: !B.Builder
                         , lbLength  :: !Int }

instance Monoid LBuilder where
    mempty = LBuilder mempty 0
    (LBuilder x1 l1) `mappend` (LBuilder x2 l2) =
        LBuilder (x1 <> x2) (l1 + l2)

char c = LBuilder (B.char7 c) 1
hPutLBuilder h = B.hPutBuilder h . toBuilder
```

As far as I understand it, this should be roughly as efficient as using `Builder` directly. But trying the following test case seems to reveal a space leak:

```
parts = replicate 10000000 $ char 'x'
main = hPutLBuilder stdout $ mconcat parts
```

Running this code takes a few seconds and consumes around 250MB of memory. Doing the same task with `Builder` is far faster and needs only 40KB. The memory profile shows that all the extra space is taken up by instances of `BuildStep` and `Builder`, which does not happen when using `Builder` directly.

What makes this code so inefficient? Why does it not happen when using `Builder`?

**Edit:**

Michael's answer below, led me to look at how `parts` is actually evaluated.
After playing around some more, I rewrote the test code in the following way:

```
makeStuff !acc 0 = acc
makeStuff !acc i = makeStuff (acc <> char 'x') (i - 1)
stuff = makeStuff mempty 10000000
-- stuffOld = mconcat $ replicate 10000000 $ char 'x'
main = hPutLBuilder stdout stuff
```

Using this definition the performance and memory usage for `Builder` and `LBuilder` is exactly the same (i.e. horrible :-). So it looks like the original version is so fast when using `Builder` because the compiler can somehow rewrite `mconcat $ replicate n $ char c` into something like `B.lazyByteString $ L.replicate n (toAscii c)` at compile time, instead of composing 10000000 functions at runtime on the heap. I tried to confirm this by looking at the generated core. I could tell that:

- The definition for `stuffOld` is a call to a relatively short function that does something with types in `Data.ByteString.Builder.Internal`.
- The definition for `stuff` is a call to `makeStuff`.
- Said core was not meant to be understood by mere mortals.

So I guess this is just the benchmark being a pathological case, and the actual performance problem in my application lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that forcing evaluation of the `mconcat parts` expression forces evaluation of its `lbLength`, which in turn will force evaluation of all the individual `char 'x'` values, which is where the space leak seems to come from. However, the only way I've found to get performance of your code to be the same as the original `Builder` is to use a `newtype` around `B.Builder`. Even just `data LBuilder = LBuilder !B.Builder` introduces significant overhead.

Comment: Hm. Does `char 'x'` really have to be evaluated more than once? In other words, are there really individual `char 'x'` values, or is there just a single one which is referenced many times?

Comment: That's not an easily answered question, it has to do with GHC's sharing rules. Lifting out `char 'x'` to a top-level definition will likely force the value to be shared.